# Maximum callstack size exceeded when trying to ajax post a list of selected checkboxes

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a page which is being populated with a list of checkboxes for each record in the database. The user can select as many checkboxes as they want and the system should save their responses. I'm having a hard time getting my array of selected checkboxes to pass through to my Controller.

When i run my code and click the submit button i get a Maximum call stack size exceeded and i'm not sure how to solve that. 
Image of the browser console error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXGfg.jpg

.cshtml:

```
    @{
          ViewBag.Title = "Subject";
     }

   <head>
       <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
       <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

</head>

<h2>Explore Subjects</h2>

<div>
        <button id="SubmitButton">Save Changes</button>
        <div  style="border-bottom:solid">
            <h4>Your Followed Subjects</h4>
            <div id="FollowedSubjects">
                @foreach (var subject in Model.FollowedSubjects)
                { 
                        <input type="checkbox" name="SubjectCheckBox" checked="checked" value=@subject.SubjectId>@subject.SubjectDetail.Subject<br>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="AllSubjects">
            <br />
            <h4>More Subjects to Follow</h4>
            <p>Ordered by number of bills with subject</p>
            @foreach(var subject in Model.AllSubjects)
            {
                <div class="subjectDisp">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SubjectCheckBox" value=@subject.Subject.SubjectId>@subject.Subject.Subject  (@subject.Count) <br>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#SubmitButton').click(function () {
            var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("SubjectCheckBox");
            var checked = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
                    checked.push(checkboxes[i]);
                }
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("FollowSubjects", "Home")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { Parameters: checked },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
            alert("there")
        });
    });
</script>
```

My controller funtion that im trying to call.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FollowSubjects(int[] Parameters)
    {
        int i = 0;
        return View();
    }
```

Eventually i will have this hit the database but for now i just put a breakpoint at int i = 0; to see what gets passed to the function.

Comment: your problem is with js, probably the code gets stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: I updated the javascript for loop to be: 
            for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
                    checked.push(checkboxes[i].values);
                }
            }

when i check the contents of that array now it is populated with just ints which is what i want but when i test clicking the button i get a 500 error in the console.

Comment: error 500 is server error, you're probably not sending the data in the way the server is expecting it;
try using jquery `checked.push($(checkboxes[i]).val());`
you can also look in the browser console, see every request check the data that you're sending

Comment: So i checked the code in my controller. The function gets the parameters it needs. I'll have to look into some other part of my code for the 500 error. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can send it as an array of string and convert them to int at server side or Stringify it and send

```
var checked=""
$(checkboxes).each(function () {
                checked += this + ',';
                i++;
```

ajax --> data: { Parameters: checked },

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FollowSubjects(string Parameters)
        {
            // Do your task 

            return View();
        }
```